# High school math books in other countries

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, education

I am a pretty fresh high school math teacher in Belgium. I'm using Dutch mathbooks, which are good, but I am looking for different perspectives. What mathbooks are popular in US highschools? What about the UK? France? Preferrably English or French books.

Thanks,

Jef

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: You could take a look at https://www.maa.org/   and   https://www.ams.org/home/page  Both have reviews of books  in there journals. I remember my favorite high school teacher, Mr. Titterton, subscribed to the MAA  journal  https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly   If this becomes important, you or someone in your school could join the MAA. I imagine France has similar  associations; also, for that matter, England.

Comment: You would probably do better to post on the [math educators site](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com).